# How to wrap a swing component in a javaFX 2.0 application

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

The ability to wrap a swing component in a javaFX application seems to have vanished from javaFX 2:

> javafx.ext.swing.SwingComponent

is not there any more in javaFX 2 beta API.

Is there still a way to do this in the new API?

Comment: Oracle is planning this for Java(FX) 8. See [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm)

Answer (score 5):

**SwingNode** class is used to embed a Swing content into a JavaFX application. 
Here is the  [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html).

Comment: This is the [link](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) for JavaFX 12.

Answer (score 3):

There is 3rd-party support library, see http://rkennke.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/swing-in-javafx-demo/

Comment: For the library link, this demo is part of the ThingsFX project: https://github.com/thingsfx/ThingsFX

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue on the FX 2.0 JIRA they aren't planning to support it in the initial release of FX 2.0. There's also no promise that they will do it down the road.

http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-12100

Answer (score 0):

It seems that since javafx 2.0+, we can't embed Swing component into JavaFX (vice versa is possible, using JFXPanel class), detail in this link:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2364553&tstart=0

I accidentally found this link when trying to embed Swing Calendar view component into JavaFX 2.0 application (which I suppose it's possible at the beginning).