# Does JavaFX 2.0 binding support work with Swing components?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Is it possible to use the new JavaFX 2.0 binding together with Swing components (JTextField, JFormattedTextField, etc...)?

*Note*: I have already asked this question in [another forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2229597&tstart=0) but as I haven't got any answer from there, I'm asking it there too.

Answer (score 2):

please follows link that posted by [eugener](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm) in thread [How to wrap a swing component in a javaFX 2.0 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157277/how-to-wrap-a-swing-component-in-a-javafx-2-0-application)

Comment: I was looking for a standardized way to do binding in my Swing application. I thought JavaFX 2.0 would be this way, but I think I have to look at alternatives like JGoodies binding because I don't want to go through JavaFX native components and wraping things in my application just to use a feature (binding in this case). I would like to have a way to bind directly to Swing components.

Comment: @Marcos ??? if something exists and has support (non free) then why not, back to JavaFX long time (maybe I blind) any news about JavaFX, or try to look for official support by Netbeans ....

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm afraid I didn't understand your comment. Could you elaborate on it a little more? Are you in favor or not of JavaFX binding with Swing? Or are you in favor of JGoodies binding, for example?

Comment: I'm afraid that JavaFX doesn't any progress long time, but JGoodies lokks like as better option, but this Framework is based on Swing, just with usage by own LayoutManager and Look and Feel