# how to use ArcGis in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, arcgis

i am using ArcGIS Library for a geospatial project. the sample codes available in their website was fully in java Swing. i need to do path animation in it using javaFX. is it possible.? if yes, can any one suggest me a sample code to create a map.?
[Sample code for creating a map in Swing](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/sample-code/basic-map/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can pull this off using `JavaFX`, since [`JMap`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-java/apiref/com/esri/map/JMap.html) extends `JComponent` and is a class provided by the `ArcGIS`. Unless, they release a version which is supporting `JavaFX`, things are not very good.

The least you can do is to embed this `JMap` into a `JavaFX` application using [`SwingNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html). An example on how to achieve this can be [found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm).

I am not sure what you want to achieve, when you say "path animation in it", but if it has something that can be achieved without using the internal components of `JMap`, you can do it !

Comment: Actually i am using JMap just to show a map and use zoom in zoom out options. i am using SQL to get the LAT/LONG values and create a path on the map and make an object move on the path. is it possible to perform..?

Comment: Is the path specific to `JMap` ? if not, you can create a similar thing using [Path Transition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CJAFDCGH)

Comment: i think its to JMap. will create a path on JMap only.

Comment: Then why not do it JMap way ?

Comment: yes. i saw the samples just now. its available directly in JMap. thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha: Can JMap be used with JavaFx? and do all the stuff with JavaFX using JMap?

Answer (score 0):

[`JMap`](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/api-reference/com/esri/map/JMap.html) is a Swing component.  JavaFX 1 was built on Swing and supported wrapping a Swing component. JavaFX 2 does not use Swing and does not support wrapping a Swing component. It is anticipated that the upcoming JavaFX 8 will support using Swing components in a JavaFX application.

UPDATE: ArcGIS Runtime is getting support for JavaFX! See http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/09/17/arcgis-runtime-plays-at-10-2-4/ for details.

You have some options:

- Go back to JavaFX 1 (not a good idea IMO)
- Turn it around and use JavaFX components in a Swing application (see http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm)
- Wait for Java 8, or go get the developer preview of Java 8.
- Wait for ArcGIS Runtime 10.2.4 (to be released any day now), which will have beta support for JavaFX.

Sources:

[How to wrap a swing component in a javaFX 2.0 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157277/how-to-wrap-a-swing-component-in-a-javafx-2-0-application)

[Class SwingNode (JavaFX 8)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but... ArcGIS Runtime for Java's latest beta (Quartz) offers much more JavaFX support.

https://developers.arcgis.com/java/beta/guide/release-notes-java.htm